# Навигация между экранами React Native (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Как сделать навигацию между двумя экранами в react native?

При компиляции данного кода получаю ошибку: `can't find variable ProfileScreen.`

```
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const App = StackNavigator({
  Main: {screen: MainScreen},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
});

class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Используйте Navigator - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html, либо как альтернативу https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Answer (score 0):

Если это весь код, тогда вы не описали ProfileScreen, сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Jane's profile</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```